# Invalid initialization of reference type 'Class&' from expression of type 'Class'

Tags: class, sorting, stl

Ok guys , so I have a list of objects and I want to sort my list by a boolean function I created .

Function ->

```
 bool funct(Student &s1,Student &s2)
{
    return s1.calculMedie()<s2.calculMedie();

}
```

I got this list:

```
list<Student*> list;
list.push_back(sx[0]);
list.push_back(sx[1]);
list.push_back(sx[2]);
```

sx is comming from this declaration-> `Student **sx=new Student*[3];`
I created 3 objects of the type class Student.

I want to sort them by 'calculMedie()' which is a function that returns their average grade.

```
double Student::calculMedie()
{
    int nr=0;
    double s=0;
    for(auto i : note)
       {
         nr++;
         s=s+i;
       }

       return s/nr;}
```

^ thats how it looks.

And when I tried to do a `list.sort(list.begin(),list.end(),funct)` it gets me this error : " Invalid initialization of reference type 'Class&' from expression of type 'Class'"

Comment: You have a list of `Student*`pointers, not a list of `Student` objects. To sort that, you need a function that takes, and can compare, a pair of `Student*` pointers. Or better, change your list to `list<Student>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mixed `std::sort` algorithm with `list<T>::sort` method. List can be sorted only by using its `sort` method.

There are two overloads of `list::sort`:

```
 void sort();   
 template< class Compare > 
 void sort( Compare comp ); // [2]
```

if you want to sort by comparator, write as follows:

```
list<Student*> list;
list.sort (funct);
```

because list stores pointers to `Student`, you need to modify signature of funct function, it must takes pointers not references:

```
bool funct(Student* s1,Student* s2)
{
    return s1->calculMedie()<s2->calculMedie();
}
```

good practice is to pass s1,s2 as pointers to *const* object, when you change s1,s2 to be `const Student* s1, const Student* s2` you need also to make `calculMedie` as *const* member function.